# Approximation of a random variable by a sequence of simple random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It said in a probability book that any non-negative random variable $X$ can be approximated by a sequence of simple random variables (finite range) $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ such that $lim_{n->\infty}X_n=X$.

Now the sequence of simple random variable is defined as :

$X_n(\omega)=k2^{-n} \text{where} k2^{-n} \leq X(\omega) \lt (k+1)2^{-n}$ \text{where} $k=0$ to $2^{2n}-1$

```
     = 0 otherwise
```

I have some doubts regarding this construction :

i) why the first term in this sequence starts with a horizontal interval of length $2^{-1}$ with the number of intervals $2^{1}$. Is there any specific reason to it ? I understand that the range of $X_n$ spans over $2^n$ to make sure that $X_n$ converges to $X$ asap.

ii) Is this construction unique ?

Answer (score 1):

i) Why not? (But the conditions $k2^{-n}\leqslant X(\omega)\leqslant(k+1)2^{-n}$ in the definition of $X_n(\omega)$ should read $k2^{-n}\leqslant X(\omega)\lt(k+1)2^{-n}$.)

ii) No.